# AngularJS SEO Meta and Description Tags

Tags: angularjs, seo

I have started to make some AngularJS applications for mobiles and recently client has asked to ship one of these to the Desktop to making it responsive multi-channel architecture.

I have seen this on a few sites:

```
<meta name="keywords" ng-if="Meta.keywords" ng-attr-content="{{ Meta.keywords }}">
<meta name="description" ng-if="Meta.description" ng-attr-content="{{ Meta.description }}">
```

When Google or other robots scan this can they see the output HTML keyword data and also this applies to content and title tags. How good is Angular for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google processes JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) so content generated within it is available to googlebot to crawl. Other crawlers have not stated whether they can or not so until it is confirmed they do it should be assumed that this content will not be available to them.

FYI, meta tags have no effect on rankings. The meta description *might* be displayed in Google's search results [but not always](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/15974/1253).

Comment: I knew about the Meta tags but the JavaScript is interesting. Do you think Google favors AngularJS and their own products over other sites?

Comment: I doubt it. As long as they can parse it they'll consider it all equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="keywords" ng-if="Meta.keywords" ng-attr-content="{{ Meta.keywords }}">
<meta name="description" ng-if="Meta.description" ng-attr-content="{{ Meta.description }}">
```

**hint**:
to avoid having this in your index.html file (e.g. for non js crawlers or if something breaks with js)  simply put a directive to your head tag. this is the cleanest way. look at this [directive](https://github.com/w11k/w11k-angular-seo-header/blob/master/angular-seo-header.js) which renders canonical, keywords, meta into your head tag.

to map your own directive to the head-tag set

```
restrict: 'E',
```

and

```
angular.module('app').directive('head', ['$rootScope'
function($rootScope) {
```

### ---

*i have sites where google definitely listens to the contents of my angular-rendered canonical tag (no html snapshots, plain single page application with a sitemap).*

Comment: Hey @Carka, I am having that kind of issue, google is indexing my Page but the meta description and title are not right and I have to wait like 2 weeks. Any idea if this can solve the issue ?